# Is it necessary to typecast the void pointer before assigning it to another pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i = 10, *j;
    void *k;
    k = &i;
    j = k;
    printf("%f", *j);
    return 0;
}
```

The above gives output 10.000000 in the GCC compiler.

My doubt is, we should write the expression `j = k` as `j = (float *)k`, right?

Comment: In C all pointers can implicitly be converted to *and from* `void *`. That's why using functions like `malloc` [without casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) works.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not required. As per `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3,

> *A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.*

So, in your case,

```
k = &i;   // no cast needed
j = k;    // again, no cast needed
```

is functionally same as

```
j = &i;
```

No explicit cast is needed here.